# Make a query, but ignore children of a given element even if they match

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html :

```
<div id="container1">

    <div id="container3">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>

    <div id="container2">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item2"></div>
    </div>

<div>
```

With jQuery, is there a (simple) way to search for divs with `.item`, but masking all the results inside `#container2`?

Ideally I'd like something like `$(#container1).mask('container2').find('.item')`, i.e. a transparent solution that you could use with any other query, without knowing that you are using it. For example :

```
// where queryExcludingContainer2 could be `$(#container1).mask('container2')` if the `mask` function existed
queryExcludingContainer2.find('.item')
queryExcludingContainer2.find('.item2')
```

Is there such a "masking" feature?

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean, but, have you tried with $('#container1 .item') ??

Comment: This will select also '.item' in '#container2'

Comment: sorry, I meant $('#container1>.item')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yhbK7/)

```
$('div').not('#container2').children('.item')
```

For more Information:
[**jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) of `not()`

Comment: Yeah... that looks perfect!

Comment: didn't know you could use `not` just as a mask

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7XkQ/).

```
$("#container1").children(".item").css('font-style', 'italic');
```

Comment: sorry, bad example. Elements are not necessarily children. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ":not" selector
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$('.item:not(#container2 *)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use `space-bar` like this:

```
$('#container1 .item')
```

And, if `.item` element was under the `#container1` directly, you can also use this:

```
$('#container1 > .item')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).